# jquery ajax in nodejs can not get/post with https

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, https

```
    var app, express, fs, jquery, jsdom;

    jsdom = require('jsdom');

    fs = require('fs');

    express = require('express');

    jquery = fs.readFileSync('./jquery-2.0.3.min.js').toString();

    jsdom.env({
      html: '<html></html>',
      src: [jquery],
      done: function(errors, window) {
        var $;
        $ = window.$;
        window.print = console.log;
        console.log(errors);
        return $.ajax({
          url: "https://www.baidu.com",
          type: "GET",
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            return print(jqXHR.url + " " + jqXHR.status + " " + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
          },
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            return console.log(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });

    app = express();

    app.listen('3000', function() {});
```

I am going to migrate a project to nodejs.
It use jquery ajax to communicate a https backend.

the above demo response is :

```
location.replace(location.href.replace("https://","http://"));
```

how can I make a https call in nodejs&jquery ajax

ps: I can't get any package from fiddler if I use nodejs+jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm sure it's possible to use jQuery and jsDom to accomplish this, there are much more tried and true libraries for this. For instance, many node developers use the [requestjs library](https://github.com/request/request)

So instead of

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://www.baidu.com",
      type: "GET",
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return print(jqXHR.url + " " + jqXHR.status + " " + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

You would do:

```
request(
    uri: "https://www.baidu.com",
    method: "GET",
    function(err, res, body){
        // handle the err and do what you want with the response
});
```